# nexus - unable to upload to snapshots repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I have an OSS Nexus instance installed and I'm trying to get my artifacts into its `snapshots` and `releases` repositories (which are hosted repositories). I'm doing it using `deployment` user credentials (I changed its password). Now, the problem is I can deploy to `releases` but can't deploy to `snapshots`. If I run `mvn deploy` on an artifact with the version like `1.2.3` -- it deploys just fine, but if I add `-SNAPSHOT` to it and try to deploy that using *exact same* credentials, it gives me back error 401. According to Nexus troubleshooting knowledgebase article, it means that either credentials were not sent or they're invalid. But they *are* sent -- I ran Maven with `-X` and it shows this user, and they are the same for both deployments. Nothing in the logs gives me any hints on why the problem occured. Actually, there're nothing at all in logs on this.

Any ideas on what's happening and how to fix that?

**Update 1:** it seems like my Nexus instance can't handle snapshot uploads. When I run `mvn deploy` on a snapshot version, what actually gets posted is something like: `/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/myorg/myapp/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/myapp-1.2.3-2014101.1234-1.jar`. But Nexus just doesn't handle it, doesn't even check for authentication.

But when I tried to manually post it as `/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/myorg/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/myapp-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar` - it worked! So it seems that these automatically generated versions cause this problem. Now, Maven has a setting `distributionManagement/snapshotRepository/uniqueVersion` in `pom.xml` which is supposed to control this behaviour, but it doesn't work in Maven 3.

**Update 2:** My `settings.xml`:

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>s1</id>
      <username>deployment2</username>
      <password>****</password>
    </server>       
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>deployment2</username>
        <password>****</password>
    </server>       
</servers>
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>s1</id>
        <url>http://myserv:15999/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <url>http://myserv:15999/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Settings of the `Snapshots` repository in Nexus:

```
Repository ID: snapshots
Repository Name: Snapshots
Repository Type: hosted
Provider: Maven2
Format: maven2
Repository Policy: Snapshot
Default Local Storage Location: file:/home/me/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/snapshots/
Override Local Storage Location: 
Deployment Policy: Allow Redeploy
Allow File Browsing: True
Include in Search: True
Publish URL: True
Not Found Cache TTL: 1440 minutes
```

**Update 3:** so I ran maven with `FINE` logging level and got this for snapshots:

```
Oct 16, 2014 6:17:32 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection writeRequests
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@1b9199bc6 pairs: {PUT /nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/myorg/myapp/0.13.23-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.13.23-20141016.151730-1.war HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-Maven/3.1.0 (Java 1.7.0_55; Windows 7 6.1)}{Host: myserv:15999}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 29473552}
Oct 16, 2014 6:17:32 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getInputStream
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@37aea9528 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized}{Date: Thu, 16 Oct 2014 15:17:31 GMT}{Server: Nexus/2.10.0-02}{X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/nexus; Max-Age=0; Expires=Wed, 15-Oct-2014 15:17:31 GMT}{WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"}{Content-Length: 0}
Oct 16, 2014 6:17:32 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1 run
FINEST: Requesting Authentication: host =myserv url = http://myserv:15999/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/com/myorg/myapp/0.13.23-SNAPSHOT/myapp-0.13.23-20141016.151730-1.war
Oct 16, 2014 6:17:32 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1 run
FINEST: Authentication returned: null
Oct 16, 2014 6:17:32 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getServerAuthentication
FINER: Server Authentication for AuthenticationHeader: prefer BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" returned null
```

And for releases:

```
Oct 16, 2014 6:42:20 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection writeRequests
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@4e90dc46 pairs: {PUT /nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/myorg/myapp/0.13.24/myapp-0.13.24.war HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-Maven/3.1.0 (Java 1.7.0_55; Windows 7 6.1)}{Host: myserv:15999}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Connection: keep-alive}{Content-Length: 29473533}
Oct 16, 2014 6:42:21 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getInputStream
FINE: sun.net.www.MessageHeader@60b5fe698 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized}{Date: Thu, 16 Oct 2014 15:42:20 GMT}{Server: Nexus/2.10.0-02}{X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/nexus; Max-Age=0; Expires=Wed, 15-Oct-2014 15:42:20 GMT}{WWW-Authenticate: BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"}{Content-Length: 0}
Oct 16, 2014 6:42:21 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1 run
FINEST: Requesting Authentication: host =myserv url = http://myserv:15999/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/myorg/myapp/0.13.24/myapp-0.13.24.war
Oct 16, 2014 6:42:21 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$1 run
FINEST: Authentication returned: java.net.PasswordAuthentication@62b1fb50
Oct 16, 2014 6:42:21 PM sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection getServerAuthentication
FINER: Server Authentication for AuthenticationHeader: prefer BASIC realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" returned sun.net.www.protocol.http.BasicAuthentication@51774036
```

As you can see, authentication info is returned for releases, but not returned for snapshots. I can't see what I could do wrong, you saw my configuration, it's pretty simple. Any ideas?

Comment: You most likely have some sort of problem in the authentication config. Please show us your settings and pom snippets and also ensure that the target repository has the snapshot policy and allows redeploy.

Comment: Manfred, I've updated my question with the information

Comment: Looks like an issue with the deployment2 user. I would suggest to try with the admin user for testing. If that works you know its a security setup issue..

Comment: Manfred, I've investigated further and found out that indeed the problem is Maven, but I can't see how my configuration could be wrong, after all, there's not much of a configuration.

Comment: So you are saying it also fails with the admin user?

Comment: Also .. maybe try using the same serverId for both... maybe its just a typo in the password

Comment: Manfred, I've tried different combinations and it seems no matter which credentials and which repositories I use, when I publish snapshots, authentication just doesn't happen. I've even tried removing `snapshotRepository` section altogether and just publish into `releases` - it doesn't authenticate when deploying snapshot and __does__ when deploying release.

Comment: Create a new Maven 2 hosted repo with snapshot policy and try deploying to it .. maybe something on your repo is hosed. And on the other side of things try a different project .. e.g. one from https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/master/maven